# Is there an ideal place to set up my server to reach the blockchain faster?

Tags: development

I'm looking for recommendations on the best geographical location or hosting provider that can offer low-latency connectivity and high-speed access to the blockchain network. If you have any suggestions or insights on finding the ideal place to host my server for improved blockchain performance, I would greatly appreciate your input - elchuo160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a provider like [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/) might benefit you. As [QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/) has a global network of nodes with automatic DNS routing and load balancing, it ensures you connect to the best and nearest node automatically. This gives you the freedom to set up your server at the location of your choice.